# App recently published on play store but app doesn't open

Tags: java, android, ionic-framework, google-play

Recently I published my ionic capacitor app on play store, when I tr to open the app after installing it is showing this error.

> java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -1  at a1.a.u(Unknown Source:76)
> at g2.q0.h(Unknown Source:27)   at g2.q0.(Unknown Source:113)
> at g2.e.P(Unknown Source:75)    at g2.e.N(Unknown Source:23)    at
> g2.e.(Unknown Source:119)   at g2.e.(Unknown Source:0)    at
> g2.e$b.c(Unknown Source:108)  at g2.f.M(Unknown Source:19)    at
> g2.f.onStart(Unknown Source:32)   at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1392)
> at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7252)    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:2970)
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:180)
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:165)
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:142)
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)     at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)    at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
> Blockquote

But my app still working on my emulator without showing any errors. How can I fix this? Pls help ...

Comment: did you test your release (signed) apk before publishing? There might be something using your debug certi's hashes which is changed when you sign with some other key

Comment: No... could you please explain in details. I am newbie to this.

Comment: try ionic capacitor build android. Afterwards go to the path of that apk and install it on your device via command shell => "adb install xxx.apk". Or send it by mail to your phone and open the apk from the mail. Than you can see if it starts. If it crashes, you will be able to call adb logcat to see the error.

Comment: Please add first initial row of error, the one starting with "Caused by: ....."

Answer (score 0):

Did you include crashlytics in your application? it is a package by Google Firebase which helps you find, isolate and fix crashes in your app.

It could be that your application won't work on a physical device, or on some of the 1000's of devices out there in the world. Try adding some crash logging to isolate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I just deleted the test files inside Android.

**Files**: **android/app/test and android/app/androidTest**

I also removed these lines

1. **testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner**" from **build.gradle** under **android-> defaultConfig**
2. **testImplementation "junit:junit:$junitVersion"
   androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$androidxJunitVersion"
   androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$androidxEspressoCoreVersion"** these lines from **build.gradle** under **dependencies**